# Help identify a trivia game

Tags: identify-this-game

This is a long shot.....I used to play a trivial pursuit type game in the early/mid 90s.

There was a board, it was similar to trivial pursuit in that you had a dice that you rolled to then move your counter around the board to reach the categories and when you had answered one question in all the categories you moved to the centre of the board.

The only things I fully remember about it was that the yellow category was up close pictures of things and the orange category was a wild card, in which you could choose to answer a category of your choice. I cannot remember what any of the categories were other than the close up pictures and the wild card (probably because these were my favourite).

Does anyone have any idea what this game was called?

Comment: Some other information that might help people if your able to recall.. Was there a board?  How did you win (reach end of a track/collect tokens/ answer a set number of questions)?  What are the other categories?  What country was this in? Did you play in teams or solo?  The more things you can recall no matter how small the less likely it becomes a long shot someone will recognise it.

Comment: I am in the uk. There was a board, it was similar to trivial pursuit in that you had a dice that you rolled to then move your counter around the board to reach the categories and when you had answered one question in all the categories you moved to the centre of the board. I cannot remember what any of the categories were other than the close up pictures and the wild card (probably because these were my favourite)

Comment: @ASmith that sounds like trivial pursuit there, there have been dozens of versions of the game, many themed on different fandoms or towards age groups, I don't know off hand of one that used pictures as clues, but the rest of the description matches Trivial Pursuit to a T

Comment: @ASmith I added your additional details to your question. In the future, please [edit] your question with clarifying details so that these details don't get lost in the comments.

Comment: Agreed this sounds like Trivial Pursuit.  According to a fan-site there are version where The Orange category is specifically a wild card.   I'm not put this as an answer as I can't find anything for close up pictures.  https://www.pursuingtrivia.com/categories/

Comment: @StartPlayer looks like about half the versions of trivial pursuit have wild card as the orange. I did look at this and didn't find one that sounded like it matched on the yellow card though https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Trivial_Pursuit_editions